# Why I am getting 'Mozilla' for IE?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer, user-agent

Today I installed IE 11 with windows update.

I make a request using IE, but `Request.Browser.Browser` returns 'Mozilla'. Why?

Comment: Gives a little bit of context: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2013/09/21/internet-explorer-11-user-agent-string-ua-string-sniffing-compatibility-with-gecko-webkit.aspx

Comment: and this, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869301(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For historical reasons, Internet Explorer identifies itself as a Mozilla browser.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms537503.aspx

Answer (score 2):

[User agent sniffing is bad for users](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/06/30/perils-of-user-agent-sniffing-browser-mode-document-mode-compatibility-view.aspx) and indirectly for browser vendors too. That’s why vendors try to find ways around this anti-pattern. In IE this started with version 9, when [the User-Agent string was frozen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/03/23/introducing-ie9-s-user-agent-string.aspx) to [make the life for caching proxies easier](http://zoompf.com/blog/2010/03/the-big-performance-improvement-in-ie9-no-one-is-talking-about).

Besides caching proxies, the more important problem are outdated scripts. IE 11 is better than IE 10, so it shouldn’t receive content prepared for IE 10. Since Microsoft cannot fix every old sniffing script out in the web, it had to find a way around the algorithms by [changing the UA string](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2013/09/21/internet-explorer-11-user-agent-string-ua-string-sniffing-compatibility-with-gecko-webkit.aspx) again.

The new regular UA string is:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

In Compatibility View the UA string is:

```
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C)
```

[Opera made a similar decision for Opera 15+](http://my.opera.com/ODIN/blog/2013/07/15/opera-user-agent-strings-opera-15-and-beyond), which doesn’t use Presto as rendering engine anymore. Its new UA string is:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.52 Safari/537.36 OPR/15.0.1147.100
```

The version number after `OPR/` indicates the actual Opera version, but there is no match for `Opera` anymore.

Please do not just adjust the sniffing scripts. You cannot win that race. Use client side feature detection instead whenever possible.